# RKMappingResult for multiple mapping

Tags: objective-c, design-patterns, path, mapping, restkit

I'm sending a request about an user. There are several possibilities. I'm thinking about sending a JSON like that:

```
"type1": {
    "id": 34,
    "email": "email@test.com",
    "firstname": "Juan",
    "lastname": "Ito",
    "gender": 2,
    "created_at": "2012-09-21T18:53:02Z",
    "updated_at": "2012-12-27T16:22:47Z"
}
"type2": {
    "id": 34,
    "email": "email@test.com",
    "firstname": "Juan",
    "lastname": "Ito",
    "gender": 2,
    "created_at": "2012-09-21T18:53:02Z",
    "updated_at": "2012-12-27T16:22:47Z"
}
"type3": {
    "id": 34,
    "email": "email@test.com",
    "firstname": "Juan",
    "lastname": "Ito",
    "gender": 2,
    "created_at": "2012-09-21T18:53:02Z",
    "updated_at": "2012-12-27T16:22:47Z"
}
```

Then I was thinking about a multiple `RKResponseDescriptor` but I don't know how to interpret the `RKMappingResult`. Do I have a way to refer an object to the keyPath ? Here I'm using 3 times the same `RKEntityMapping` but with different keyPaths.

Finally I don't even know if it's possible.

**Edit:**

Maybe this kind of JSON is better and easier to understand/map.

```
"type" : "type1", 
"user": {
    "id": 34,
    "email": "email@test.com",
    "firstname": "Juan",
    "lastname": "Ito",
    "gender": 2,
    "created_at": "2012-09-21T18:53:02Z",
    "updated_at": "2012-12-27T16:22:47Z"
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: That doesn't look like very nice JSON. But it really isn't clear what you're asking here... Are you asking about a request or a response? Are you misunderstanding path patterns or key paths? I have no idea currently.

Comment: Honestly I don't even know how to do it (for both the request or the response). Maybe a simple parameter inside the JSON could be better but can I add as descriptor a for a known entity and just a new parameter ? I've added another example of possible JSON.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough information to suggest about JSON structure. The arbitrary keys isn't very nice, but it is quite common. Generally a 'container' object in the JSON is nicer.

That said, RestKit can generally handle both. Check out `addAttributeMappingFromKeyOfRepresentationToAttribute:` and `addAttributeMappingToKeyOfRepresentationFromAttribute:` on [`RKObjectMapping`](http://restkit.org/api/master/Classes/RKObjectMapping.html) for examples of how to handle that kind of JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is related to how to map the response JSON using Restkit mapping then this is better way to design your JSON.

```
{"userProfile":[
{
    "id": 34,
    "email": "email@test.com",
    "firstname": "Juan",
    "lastname": "Ito",
    "gender": 2,
    "created_at": "2012-09-21T18:53:02Z",
    "updated_at": "2012-12-27T16:22:47Z"
},
{
    "id": 34,
    "email": "email@test.com",
    "firstname": "Juan",
    "lastname": "Ito",
    "gender": 2,
    "created_at": "2012-09-21T18:53:02Z",
    "updated_at": "2012-12-27T16:22:47Z"
},
 {
    "id": 34,
    "email": "email@test.com",
    "firstname": "Juan",
    "lastname": "Ito",
    "gender": 2,
    "created_at": "2012-09-21T18:53:02Z",
    "updated_at": "2012-12-27T16:22:47Z"
}
]}
```

Modal classes:

**userProfile.h**

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *userInfo;
```

**userInfo.h**

```
@property(assign) int id;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *email;
```

.......

Mapping can be done with **AttributeMapping** and **RelationshipMapping**

Answer (score 0):

I finally mapped the `type` like this:

```
RKObjectMapping *typeMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[typeMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"type":@"type"}];
```

With this descriptor:

```
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:typeMapping
                                                                                         method:RKRequestMethodAny
                                                                                    pathPattern:nil
                                                                                        keyPath:nil
                                                                                    statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

Basically to catch this dictionary, basically I did this:

```
NSString *type = [((NSDictionary *)[[mappingResult array] objectAtIndex:0]) objectForKey:@"type"];
```

This solve my problem because just after I'm selecting different actions according to the value of `type`.

I let @Wain tell us if this method is acceptable or not.